# Graficar datos de una hoja excel con Python

Tags: python, excel

Quería hacer una gráfica de los datos que tengo en un excel usando python. En la primera columna del excel tengo valores de tiempo (eje x), y en las otras columnas valores de inensidad (eje y) para cada tiempo.

Por lo que he leído, puedo usar openpyxel para leer el excel. Luego imagino que pasar las valores a una matriz de numpy, y luego hacer la gráfica con matplotlib.

No se si lo estoy planteando bien.

¿Podríais decirme si se haría así? Un pequeño ejemplo sería magnífico!

Comment: Echa un ojo a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), te resolvería el problema en unas pocas líneas de código.

Comment: Hola kikocorreoso,  me lo miraré,  no lo conocía. Gracias!

Comment: Dale un vistazo también a [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) Permite integrar librerías de Python (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.) además de sustituir VBA por funciones que crees en Python. En concreto, para el problema que planteas:
http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html

Comment: Gracias! No lo conocía, le hecho un vistazo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aclaro que nunca había usado openpyxel antes (por si meto la pata...XD). Usando [`Openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/), NumPy y matplotlib:

```
from itertools import cycle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#cargamos el xlsx en memoria
wb = load_workbook('datos.xlsx', data_only=True)
#cargamos la hoja
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

#creamos la matriz en numpy
matriz = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row, sheet1.max_column))

#leemos la hoja fila por fila y vamos guardando los valores 'x' e 'y'
for i in range(0,sheet1.max_row):
    for j in range(0,sheet1.max_column):
        matriz[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value

#creamos el grafico
colors = cycle(["aqua", "black", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "green", "lime", "maroon", "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow"])
plt.xlabel('tiempo')
plt.ylabel('intensidad')
for y in range(1, sheet1.max_column):
    plt.plot(matriz[:,0],matriz[:,y], label="Data " + str(y),       color=next(colors))
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0,70)
plt.ylim(0,70)
plt.title('Grafica tiempo/intensidad')
plt.show()
```

Lo he probado con un documento (al que he llamado datos.xlsx) hecho en LibreOffice y guardado con formato .xlsx de Excel porque no tengo a mano excel [^_^]. El documento tiene 4 columnas (1 con los valores de x y 3 con valores de y) con datos inventados:

```
0   2   4   6
1   4   8   12
2   6   12  18
3   8   16  24
4   10  20  30
5   12  24  36
6   14  28  42
7   16  32  48
8   18  36  54
9   20  40  60
10  22  44  66
11  24  48  72
12  26  52  78
13  28  56  84
14  30  60  90
15  32  64  96
16  34  68  102
17  36  72  108
18  38  76  114
19  40  80  120
20  42  84  126
21  44  88  132
22  46  92  138
23  48  96  144
24  50  100 150
25  52  104 156
26  54  108 162
27  56  112 168
28  58  116 174
29  60  120 180
30  62  124 196
```

Con esto y usando Python 3.5.2 me sale esta gráfica tan fea:
[image: Grafica]

Es solo un ejemplo que espero que te sirva de algo. Yo al menos he descubierto openpyxl, por si en un futuro necesito algo asi nunca esta de más :)

P.D: para cargar la hoja correspondiente en la linea

```
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
```

Necesitamos el nombre de la hoja (Hoja1 en mi caso). Puedes obtener el nombre de todas las hojas del xlsx de la siguiente forma:

```
print(wb.get_sheet_names())
```

**Modificada para aclarar duda expresada en comentarios:**

Si en la primera fila tenemos etiquetas que muestran que contienen cada columna y queremos que aparezcan en la leyenda de la gráfica bastará con empezar a leer desde la segunda fila los datos y leer lugo de la hoja la celda correspondiente al nombre de cada columna pasandoselo como atributo 'label' a 
    matplotlib.pyplot
Por ejemplo para unos datos de la forma:

```
t   Datos 1 Datos 2 Datos 3
0   2   4   6
1   4   8   12
2   6   12  18
3   8   16  24
```

El código siguente realiza la gráfica usando como etiquetas 'Datos 1', 'Datos 2' y 'Datos 3':

```
from itertools import cycle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#cargamos el xlsx en memoria
wb = load_workbook('datos.xlsx', data_only=True)
#cargamos la hoja
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

#creamos dos arreglos en numpy para guardar las 'x' y las 'y'
matriz = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row, sheet1.max_column))

#leemos la hoja columna por columna y vamos guardando los valores 'x' e 'y'
for i in range(1,sheet1.max_row):
    for j in range(0,sheet1.max_column):
        matriz[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value

#creamos el grafico
colors = cycle(["aqua", "black", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "green", "lime", "maroon", "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow"])
plt.xlabel('tiempo')
plt.ylabel('intensidad')
for y in range(1, sheet1.max_column):
    plt.plot(matriz[:,0],matriz[:,y], label=sheet1.cell(row=1,    column=y+1).value,color=next(colors))
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0,70)
plt.ylim(0,70)
plt.title('Grafica tiempo/intensidad')
plt.show()
```

Comment: FJSevilla, funciona genial, muchísimas gracias!! Dos cositas: 1) En la leyenda del gráfico me aparece como que tiene datos de 999 columnas; ¿me está computando todas las columnas que puede dar una hoja de excel?. 2)Para rizar un poco el rizo, si en la primera fila tengo palabras identificando que es cada columna, ¿puedo hacer que cada identificativo de la columna aparezca en la leyenda? (menos la palabra que corresponde a la primera columna, que es el tiempo y es el eje x). Muchas gracias!

Comment: En cuanto a la primera duda en mi caso no pasa, solo lee las columnas que contienen algo y no columnas vacias, si te pasa algo hay diferente en tu documento de exel. Como comenté nunca he usado Openpyxl y puede que se me escape algo, sin tener el archivo que tu usas no se decirte ahora mismo que ocurre. Lo que puedes hacer es si conoces el numero de columnas simplemente cambiar sheet1.max_column por ese numero.

Comment: En cuanto a la segunda si tiene fácil solución, simplemente empieza a leer los datos para almacenar en el array desde la fila 2 y no desde la uno y luego al crear el gráfico le pasas al parametro label el valor correspondiente leyendo la celda del .xlsx. Voy a modificar la respuesta añadiendo al final de la misma esta consideración.

Comment: Genial! Funciona perfecto! No me ha vuelto a pasar lo que comentaba en la primera duda, así que debí hacer algo mal... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor y más práctico es usar la biblioteca pandas. Crea un archivo de excel con las caracteristicas que pusiste en tu pregunta, libro1.xlsx (dos culumnas una del tiempo y otra de instensidad).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego sigue el código abajo

```
import pandas as pd
# defines el camino donde esta tu archivo de excel
filename = '/camino/libro1.xlsx'
# lectura del archivo excel usando la función pd.read_excel
dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename)
print dataframe.head()  # esto te imprime los primeros 5 elementos
   tiempo  intensidad
0       1         132
1       2          34
2       3         543
3       4         453
4       5         654
```

ya para plotear tus datos basta con usar la biblioteca matplotlib, aqui un ejemplo

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dataframe['tiempo'], dataframe['intensidad'])
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial!! Otro usuario ya había comentado que con Pandas se podía hacer bien, pero no había enido tiempo de mirarlo... Muchas gracias por el código, funciona muy bien.

Comment: De nada, si la respuesta fue útil es bueno dar flecha arriba para contribuir con la respuesta.

Comment: Si, le dí! Pero tengo menos de 15 puntos de reputación y no aparece como marcado, aunque sale un mensaje y pone que queda registrado. Lamento no poder contribuir de otra forma a esta estupenda respuesta, sólo darte las gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

te puedo recomendar que vea este módulo de Python. [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html)
Funciona con casi todas las versiones de Python, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, Jython and PyPy. Y con Excel de 2007 en adelante. Además en la página principal hay muy buenos ejemplos.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('A1', data)

# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Muy interesante, le hecho un vistazo!